# Redirect printf to specific line on file

Tags: notifications, printf, sms, centos7

Am using centreon to send a SMS notification when a service o host is down.

I use this command with bash to send de notification:

```
curl --data @message.xml --header "Content-Type: text/xml" -X POST 'ip-server-notification'
```

this is the content of message.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<MTRequest>
    <Proveedor Id="user" Password="password" />
    <Servicio Id="" ContentType="0" ShortNumber="shor number" />
    <Telefono msisdn="my phone" IdTran=""/>
    <Contenido>DATA</Contenido>
</MTRequest>
```

I have append the ouput of centreon:

```
/usr/bin/printf "%b" "***** centreon Notification *****\n\nType:$NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\nHost: $HOSTNAME$\nState: $HOSTSTATE$\nAddress: $HOSTADDRESS$\nInfo: $HOSTOUTPUT$\nDate/Time: $DATE$"
```

bethen the contenidos tags

`<Contenido>Here</Contenido>`

Can you Help me?

Sorry for bad English.

best regards.

Answer (score 1):

So the in principle, you should be able to create a notification command, which can for example trigger a curl or a script that would pass the information to the API for sending the SMS.

To see the notification commands launched by centreon-engine, you must:

- Modify the Centreon-Engine configuration of the poller in question.
- Go to the "Debug" tab
- Check "Notification information" and "Commands"
- Put the highest level of detail for verbosity
- Set a maximum size because this debug is very verbose (100000000 bytes is recommended)
- Do not activate the core dump
- Save the configuration
- Generate and export the collector configuration
- Generate a notification with a test service
- Edit the file /var/log/centreon-engine/centengine.debug to find the notification command

In this file centengine.debug you will have more information on the issue.

Also you can check the documentation you might find your solution here https://documentation.centreon.com/